# import module from cocoa pod has error but is still able to build the project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, frameworks, cocoapods

I am new to creating cocoa pod, here is some questions which maybe easy for you, but these do give me a headache. here my story:

I create a swift framework project(called project A), and then put it as a cocoa pod(it does is a complicated process). and then I create another single view swift project(called project B), and then use pod to integrate the project A into project B. In my project B, I have an error when I use a  class from project A, it says: `"No such module '**class name**'"`.

So I have two questions here:

1. when I create the swift framework project, how come it has an .h file in the project: the file looks like this:

   ```
   import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   //! Project version number for VLEBluetoothKit.
   FOUNDATION_EXPORT double projectnameVersionNumber;

   //! Project version string for VLEBluetoothKit.
   FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char projectnameVersionString[];

   // In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <projectname/PublicHeader.h>
   ```

   2. why I have the error in project B, I can still build it successfully?
   3. how can I solve this error.

Thanks a lot guys. please give me a hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is the Xcode bug. Try to do the following things

1. Clean the project cmd+K
2. Reopen the XCode
3. Delete the user delivered data

Comment: Thanks Bro, but this does not seems solve the problem.